# Django QuerySet contains duplicate entries

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I'm trying to retrieve some of the contents of a table using django's ORM.

```
results = Table.objects.using('production').filter(foreign_id=76)
results.count()  # 129807
```

The `id` column of this table is the primary key and thus, has unique entries. However, the returned QuerySet has duplicate entries:

```
results[7999].id  # 27177397
results[121679].id  # 27177397
```

It's not just the `id` that is duplicate, it's the entire row. In fact, the last 8,000 results of the QuerySet are all duplicate (I think of the first 8,000 but I haven't verified).

Of course, I have verified that the `id` column in the table is unique and that, when querying for `27177397` with sql directly (or via the django ORM), I only get one result.

```
results = Table.objects.using('production').filter(id=27177397, foreign_id=76)
results.count()  # 1
```

How can this be?

I am using django 1.6.7 using pyscopg2 2.5.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filtering by foreign key force a join (also, default order by can induce a join). Use [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) to remove duplicate row:

```
results = ( Table
            .objects
            .using('production')
            .filter(foreign_id=76)
            .order_by()
            .distinct()
            )
```

Comment: oh I see, my last two days spent narrowing down this terrible result is because django can do *mysterious joins*.  That makes sense.  I like that feature. Filter by this.. order by that.. and your table joins change!  Best to keep it from showing any indication in the `results.query()` string too, otherwise it wouldn't be mysterious enough.   Thank you, @danihp, for resolving this for me. I would have never gotten there using logic and reason.